# Avoid RStudio to execute code when saving

Tags: r, rstudio

I recently installed the last version of RStudio and now every time I save a ".R" file that I'm working on, RStudio executes the code when saving it. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Source on Save` is an RStudio option, located between the tabs and the top of the source pane. If the code is executed on save, this option is probably turned on (right panel). Thus, the option need to be turned off by unchecking the option (left panel).

[image]

Comment: This option is weird and dangerous IMO.

Comment: @user3710546 - Could you please help me understand as what is the use of this option? Thank you!